# Is putting a board inside an anti-static enclosure enough to make it Ex ib ready?

Tags: safety, standard

A year ago, we made a handheld PDA based on RPi0 for a client. Now they have asked us to certificate it as **Ex ib IIC T4**.

Here is the PDA's spec:

1. RPi0 as processing board
2. 4.3" capcitive LCD
3. A 3500 mAh LiPo battery
4. Our own custum-made battery charging board based on TI's BQ24160 IC.
5. An 13.56 MHz RFID module.

We reached a certificate body and this is the test list they have asked our device to pass:

[image]

So, my question is, if we build a compeletly non-metallic anti-static enclosure without any protruding or conductive parts (according to thermal/impact criteria), does the device pass the tests? In other words, should I change the RPi0 board because of conductive/inductive curves?

Comment: Nothing passes the tests until it passes the tests. Where are the Ex ib testing/assessment that needs to be done - that doesn't appear in the list and it will need to be done. It's unlikely that your battery will be compatible irrespective of what box you put it in (other than a flameproof box) and this is not listed.

Comment: It's also likely that your company will need to pass an ISO 9000 inspection and be regularly assessed against it to ensure that your production methods and quality control are suitable.

Comment: @andy-aka Do you mean Spark ignition test?

Comment: Spark ignition testing is not part of certification. You need to hire a local expert if you want my opinion because you are out of your depth.